expo-av how to play different songs
I randomly pick a number from 1 to 99.
I want to play a different song corresponding to the number.
How to modify the playSound function to easyl change the audioFile ?
Is it possible to use a parameter for the playSound function ?
async function playSound(audioFile) {
  console.log('Loading Sound');
  const { sound } = await Audio.Sound.createAsync(require(audioFile));
  setSound(sound);
  await sound.playAsync();
  
}

I'd like to easily change the .mp3 in the playSound function.

Compose the songs into an array; keep currentSongIndex as state.  On selected index changes call playSound with arr[currentSongIndex] as  the argument

or maybe try https://rntp.dev/docs/api/hooks. It looks like it uses native modules so you'll have to go thru the loops of adding the native modules to expo av but it looks promising https://rntp.dev/docs/basics/installation#expo
